# What's the best way to get distance in R?

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial

I am looking to record distance to hospitals from SUDs centers in a county. Here's the code:

```
alameda_distances <- st_distance(alameda_SUDs_centers, alameda_mediCal_hospitals) * 0.000621371
alameda_mediCal_hospitals$distance <- (as.vector(apply(alameda_distances,1, min)))
```

But I received this error after this line of code:

```
alameda_mediCal_hospitals$distance <- (as.vector(apply(alameda_distances,1, min)))

Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(0.452148118348417, 1.15003687022296, :
replacement has 32 rows, data has 11
```

Any suggestions? I am using these libraries in RMarkdown:

```
library(janitor)
library(sf)
library(spData)
library(sp)
library(raster)
```

I tried to add "NA" to the new variable alameda_mediCal_hospitals$distance

Comment: what is the `dim(alameda_distances)`?
perhaps it is `apply(alameda_distances,2, min)`?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this:

```r
library(geosphere)
distm(c(long1, lat1), c(long2, lat2 ), fun = distHaversine)
```

It returns distance in meters.